# Summarising multiple columns column-wise in R by deselecting unwanted columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to find a way to summarise multiple columns column-wise in R by specifying the column that I don't want to summarise. For example in the following case I want do summarise all columns that are not named "cat" or "type":

This data frame:

```
df <- data_frame(cat = c('A', 'B', 'C'), 
                 val1 = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5), 
                 val2 = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.7), 
                 val3 = c(0.14, 0.31, 0.35),
                 type = c(4, 2, 5))
```

To this one:

```
df <- data_frame(cat = c('A', 'B', 'C'), 
                 val1 = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5), 
                 val2 = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.7), 
                 val3 = c(0.14, 0.31, 0.35),
                 type = c(4, 2, 5),
                 sum = c(0.44,0.81,1.55))
```

I have been trying using dplyr mutate functions to do this but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Any suggestion of how to do this would be super appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the columns that you don't want using `select` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(sum = rowSums(select(., -cat, -type)))

#  cat    val1  val2  val3  type   sum
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A       0.1   0.2  0.14     4  0.44
#2 B       0.3   0.2  0.31     2  0.81
#3 C       0.5   0.7  0.35     5  1.55
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also use `!` bang operator in `dplyr`'s `summarise(c_across(..` alongwith `rowwise` like this

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sum = sum(c_across(!c(cat, type))))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   cat    val1  val2  val3  type   sum
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A       0.1   0.2  0.14     4  0.44
#> 2 B       0.3   0.2  0.31     2  0.81
#> 3 C       0.5   0.7  0.35     5  1.55
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In base R you could do:

**Update: thanks to AnilGoyal for clarification**

To remove certain columns (in your case col1=cat and col5=type) in base R you could do:

```
df$sum <- rowSums(df[, c(-1,-5)])
```

**First answer:**

```
df$sum <- rowSums(df[2:4])
```

Output:

```
  cat    val1  val2  val3  type   sum
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A       0.1   0.2  0.14     4  0.44
2 B       0.3   0.2  0.31     2  0.81
3 C       0.5   0.7  0.35     5  1.55
```